# How to set IDENTITY_INSERT on for every table in a loop before generating insert command

Tags: sql-server

I have made a below stored procedure for generating insert command for all the tables .

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertGenerator]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tablename varchar(max)
    DECLARE @tbl table (insertVal varchar(max))

    DECLARE cursCol1 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT name FROM sys.tables WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name NOT IN ('Notification')
    
    OPEN cursCol1
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol1 INTO @tablename 
    
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE cursCol CURSOR FOR
            SELECT column_name, data_type
            FROM information_schema.columns WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE table_name = @tableName
        
        OPEN cursCol
        DECLARE @string nvarchar(max) 
        DECLARE @stringData nvarchar(max)
        DECLARE @dataType nvarchar(max)
        SET @string='INSERT '+@tableName+'('
        SET @stringData=''
        DECLARE @colName nvarchar(MAX)

        FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol INTO @colName,@dataType
        
        IF @@fetch_status <> 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Table '+@tableName+' not found, processing skipped.'
            FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol1 INTO @tablename
            CLOSE curscol
            DEALLOCATE curscol
            RETURN
        END

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            IF @dataType IN ('varchar', 'char', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
            BEGIN
                SET @stringData = @stringData + ''''''''' +
                                  ISNULL(' + @colName + ','''') + '''''',''+'
            END
            BEGIN

                SET @stringData=@stringData+'''''''''+
                    isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(MAX)),''0'')+'''''',''+'
            END
            SET @string=@string+@colName+','
            FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol INTO @colName ,@dataType
        END
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @Query nvarchar(MAX)
            
            SET @query ='SELECT '''+substring(@string,0,len(@string)) + ') 
                         VALUES(''+ ' + substring(@stringData,0,len(@stringData)-2)+'''+'')'' 
                        FROM '+@tableName

            INSERT INTO @tbl (insertVal) 
                EXEC (@query)

            PRINT (@query)
        END

        CLOSE cursCol
        DEALLOCATE cursCol
        
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol1 INTO @tablename
    END

    CLOSE cursCol1
    DEALLOCATE cursCol1  

    SELECT * FROM @tbl
END
GO
```

Now I need to set `IDENTITY_INSERT ON`  before generating insert script for every table then, `IDENTITY_INSERT OFF` after the insert statement.

I want that it should work with cursor in a loop for every table .

What modifications needs to be done .I have made a below stored procedure for generating insert command for all the tables .

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertGenerator]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tablename varchar(max)
    DECLARE @tbl table (insertVal varchar(max))

    DECLARE cursCol1 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT name FROM sys.tables WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name NOT IN ('Notification')
    
    OPEN cursCol1
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol1 INTO @tablename 
    
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE cursCol CURSOR FOR
            SELECT column_name, data_type
            FROM information_schema.columns WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE table_name = @tableName
        
        OPEN cursCol
        DECLARE @string nvarchar(max) 
        DECLARE @stringData nvarchar(max)
        DECLARE @dataType nvarchar(max)
        SET @string='INSERT '+@tableName+'('
        SET @stringData=''
        DECLARE @colName nvarchar(MAX)

        FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol INTO @colName,@dataType
        
        IF @@fetch_status <> 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Table '+@tableName+' not found, processing skipped.'
            FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol1 INTO @tablename
            CLOSE curscol
            DEALLOCATE curscol
            RETURN
        END

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            IF @dataType IN ('varchar', 'char', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
            BEGIN
                SET @stringData = @stringData + ''''''''' +
                                  ISNULL(' + @colName + ','''') + '''''',''+'
            END
            BEGIN

                SET @stringData=@stringData+'''''''''+
                    isnull(cast('+@colName+' as varchar(MAX)),''0'')+'''''',''+'
            END
            SET @string=@string+@colName+','
            FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol INTO @colName ,@dataType
        END
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @Query nvarchar(MAX)
            
            SET @query ='SELECT '''+substring(@string,0,len(@string)) + ') 
                         VALUES(''+ ' + substring(@stringData,0,len(@stringData)-2)+'''+'')'' 
                        FROM '+@tableName

            INSERT INTO @tbl (insertVal) 
                EXEC (@query)

            PRINT (@query)
        END

        CLOSE cursCol
        DEALLOCATE cursCol
        
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol1 INTO @tablename
    END

    CLOSE cursCol1
    DEALLOCATE cursCol1  

    SELECT * FROM @tbl
END
GO
```

Now I need to set IDENTITY_INSERT on before generating insert script for every table then
IDENTITY_INSERT off after the insert statement .
I want that it should work with cursor in a loop for every table .

What modifications needs to be done?
Thanks in advance
Thanks in advance .

Comment: It should be sufficient to add the `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` for the current table between your `begin` and `DECLARE cursCol CURSOR FOR`... and the `IDENTITY_INSERT OFF` between `DEALLOCATE cursCol` and `FETCH NEXT FROM cursCol1 INTO @tablename`

Comment: You can **only** specify `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` for **a single table** at any given time

Comment: In a user session, only one table can have the SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON at the same time. You neeed to set SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON just before INSERTs and SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF just after INSERTs. This limitation has been done to prevent contention in concurrency (imagine if all tables of your db is locked for this SQL execution...)

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). WHO teaches this?

Comment: @Tyron78 I tried doing as you said but still I am not able to insert the values .Error says  ''Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tablename' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. I tried this for a single table .